# Converting string into HTML Code in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting description from API

```
description = '<p>Book gor 4 hair cut and get 1 hair cut free validity is ONE year&nbsp;</p>'
```

And now I'm trying to render the same in HTML

```
<div>
     {parser.parseFromString(description,"text/html").querySelector('body').innerHTML}
</div>
```

But it's not rendering like html.  [check my fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/95293/) .
 The expected output should render the same like html tag behavior.

Comment: Why would you like to do it? Why not to keep it as a node?

Comment: @KonradD expecting output render the same like html tag behavior. that's why i'm trying do that can you please check my fiddle link and give me solution for this

Comment: what about stripping the html tags and render the text? `Book gor 4 hair cut and get 1 hair cut free validity is ONE year`

Comment: looks like somebody has build such parser without usage of dangerouslySetInnerHTML - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML, but it's not called "dangerous" just for fun...

```
<div>
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:
        parser
            .parseFromString(description,"text/html")
            .querySelector('body')
            .innerHTML
    }}
</div>
```

Comment: I guess they didn't call this method *dangerously* by accident... I just wouldn't suggest using it to anyone.

Comment: i tried that its not working. can you suggest some other solution

Answer (score 0):

Most of the approaches seem to be complicated. The approach I chose to take was, returning the entire function as a JSX element.
For eg:

```
renderJSXElement(): JSX.Element{
   return (Enter html string here)
}
```

You can pass this as a props to your js render and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let description = '<p>Book gor 4 hair cut and get 1 hair cut free validity is ONE year&nbsp;</p>';
    return (<div>
              <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:description}} />
            </div>)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score -1):

you should also be able to use Jquery as so

```
$('.description').html('<p>Book gor 4 hair cut and get 1 hair cut free validity is ONE 
            year&nbsp;</p>')
```

https://oscarotero.com/jquery/

I edited this to include parsing the response body. attaching it to the state and rendering state.description in the jsx makes it more dynamic. you can also have the function that calls the api return the parsed response body and call that in your div instead of using state. `<div>{this.getDescription()}</div>`. worst case scenario, you may have to split the description to remove the p tags and render that in the body. example: `description = res.body.split('<p>').join().split('</p>').join()`, then handle it either of the ways in my examples. if you remove the p tags you can use jquery to set the text: `$('.description').text(description)`

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            description: '<p>Book gor 4 hair cut and get 1 hair cut free validity is ONE 
            year&nbsp;</p>'
        }
        this.getDescription = this.getDescription.bind(this)
    }

        getDescription() {
            apiCall().then(res => {
                this.setState({ description : JSON.parse(res.body)})
            })
        }

        render () {
            return (
                <div className="description">
                {this.state.description}
           </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Some information about what you did / why it works would be helpful.